# How do I force users to agree to the terms on my website homepage when they arrive at another page via Google?

Tags: html

I currently have an agree to terms page on the home page of my website and this works fine when users go to my home page first. However, Google has picked up the other pages of my website.

Is it possible to make my home page appear when users go to my sub-pages? I.e. if a user goes to www.mydomain.com/firstpage, then this link takes them to my home page so they have to agree to the terms before entering the site?

Comment: you have to choose a language at least it cannot be done with hmtl :)

Comment: Closed? This is absolutely a real question. It’s fairly speculative, but the questioner is very clear about what they want to do, they just don’t know how to do it. What’s the value in closing this?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Much as I dislike the question, it seems to be clear enough that two people have independently come to the same answer.

Comment: Vote to reopen, as it is a legitimate question.  Not, however, that this may be interpreted by Google as cloaking, since it means users who click on Google links will see a different page than Google saw.  In that situation, your page may be de-ranked by Google.  In short, this strategy is really, really bad for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

If the user doesn't have an "Agreed to terms" cookie, then set a cookie to record the page they are viewing and redirect to the homepage.

When they click the I Agree submit button, set an "Agreed to terms" cookie and redirect them back to the page they were looking for.

That's how. Now don't do it as it is very obnoxious.

Comment: I say do it! Then show whichever pointy-haired manager who suggested it the traffic drop-off after it’s implemented. Then kick him in the balls.

Comment: hi david thanks, its something i have to do, any ideas where i can find advice on how to do this in html, still a novice learning here

Comment: HTML is a document markup language. You need a programming language. This is the sort of tiny little thing that I might even resort to PHP for (although having a mod_perl auth module would be more elegant). Either way, I'd value my soul too much to do it cheaply.

Comment: @Tim — even if it for a +18 site. Click through licenses are worthless at the best of times. Click through licenses that are clicked through by minors even more so.

Comment: i appreciate the comments about not doing it for traffic reasons but it is something that i wish to do and was just looking for some advice on the best way of going about this. im a beginner and thought that asking the question was worth a go

Comment: Not sure why this is a closed question, but following on from David's comment above, would this be possible using server-side configuration files rather than a programming language? For example, using .htaccess rewrite-rules on an Apache server you can check a cookie value and redirect to another page if it's not set: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh.html#modrewrite2

Comment: mod_rewrite practically qualifies as a programming language :)

Comment: trying to put my question another way. Is it possible to have all my page links that are indexed by Google automatically take you to my home page if it is the first time you have visited my site?

Comment: Yes, and if you follow the instructions in this answer, that is what you will get.

Comment: david are you referring to icabod's answer?

Comment: No, mine. Although icabod's comment does point another language you could use.

Comment: david thanks, do you have any ideas where would be the best place to start with this, bearing in mind i am a beginner but more than happy to learn

Comment: Find out what programming languages your server supports, then pick one.

Comment: ok ive looked at javascript and have found the following code. would it work if i added this code to everypage of my website. how could i alter this code to record if a user has already clicked my agree button on my home page if they have then they continue if not they get redirected to my home page:

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());

Comment: document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>

Comment: The problem with using Javascript is that if the user has Javascript disabled, it won't work. You're better off using something server-side if possible. Using something like mod_rewrite (which is not simple, I admit) would also mean that you wouldn't need to alter every page of your site.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting a cookie for example. If the user hasn't the cookie, then you redirect him to the term of use page.

Comment: hi jean-christophe thanks, its something i have to do, any ideas where i can find advice on how to do this in html, still a novice learning here

Comment: @Matt: If you're using client-side code, you cannot do so reliably.  If you're using server-side code, you need to tell us what language you are using or we cannot help you.